# How to read data from BioTime4 machine without raising an event

Tags: c#, network-programming, biometrics

I am working on a project where I need to read the data from punching machine when someone in/out from the to/from office and add that data to the data base.
We have a BioTime4 machine from Mantra Tech Software. When some one punch the card on machine it will save the data inside machine only. 
But I don't know in which format or where?
I create a sample project and get connected successfully to the machine on port 5005 
as that machine connected on that port. 
But I don't know how to read data from that machine, even that machine not rasing any event when someone puch the card. 
Their system reading data using ocx when admin click on button but that code is in ocx file so not able find from there.

We want to remove manual intervention from the system and want real time data in our company master database.
I am posting my sample code which gets connected to the machine using port.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

try
{
    var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 0, 232 }), 5005);
    var socket = new Socket(endpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 0, 67 }), 5005));
    socket.Connect(endpoint);
    MessageBox.Show("Connected...");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Can some one give idea or other link where I can proceed further.

Thanks

Comment: Tarun, did you find anything? I am also looking for something like that !

Comment: Hi Tushar, I haven't found anything yet. But now we have planned to move on BioMatrix 8 machine. That machine rasing callback event when any new data received. Still we have not purchased it but they show us a demo about that.

Comment: Good to know that Tarun, Can you also forward me the details. Working on something similar.

Comment: Hi Tushar, sorry still we have not purchased that machine, we have just seen the demo from their support team. In that demo they show that machine itself capable to send notification and generate a csv file for data on our desired location. So after that we just to need read the CSV file and save data.